# Set onclickLister in utube api

Tags: java, android, youtube

i'm using youtubeApi (https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/), I'm looking for a solution for put an onclick listener on the videos on the VideoWall..

```java
package com.android.youbho.Activities;

import static android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailLoader;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Pair;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.youbho.Utils.Constant;
import com.android.youbho.Utils.FlippingView;
import com.android.youbho.Utils.ImageWallView;

@SuppressLint("NewApi") public class VideoWallActivity extends Activity implements
FlippingView.Listener,
YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener,
YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener{
    private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;
    /** The player view cannot be smaller than 110 pixels high. */
    private static final float PLAYER_VIEW_MINIMUM_HEIGHT_DP = 110;
    private static final int MAX_NUMBER_OF_ROWS_WANTED = 4;
    // Example playlist from which videos are displayed on the video wall
    private static final String PLAYLIST_ID = "PLBA95EAD360E2B0D1";
    private static final int INTER_IMAGE_PADDING_DP = 5;
    // YouTube thumbnails have a 16 / 9 aspect ratio
    private static final double THUMBNAIL_ASPECT_RATIO = 16 / 9d;
    private static final int INITIAL_FLIP_DURATION_MILLIS = 100;
    private static final int FLIP_DURATION_MILLIS = 500;
    private static final int FLIP_PERIOD_MILLIS = 2000;
    private ImageWallView imageWallView;
    private Handler flipDelayHandler;
    private FlippingView flippingView;
    private YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView;
    private YouTubeThumbnailLoader thumbnailLoader;
    private YouTubePlayerFragment playerFragment;
    private View playerView;
    private YouTubePlayer player;
    private Dialog errorDialog;
    private int flippingCol;
    private int flippingRow;
    private int videoCol;
    private int videoRow;
    private boolean nextThumbnailLoaded;
    private boolean activityResumed;
    private State state;
    private static final int id_videoPlayer=99;

    private enum State {
        UNINITIALIZED,
        LOADING_THUMBNAILS,
        VIDEO_FLIPPED_OUT,
        VIDEO_LOADING,
        VIDEO_CUED,
        VIDEO_PLAYING,
        VIDEO_ENDED,
        VIDEO_BEING_FLIPPED_OUT,
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      View view = convertView;
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "lol:" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


      return view;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        state = State.UNINITIALIZED;

        ViewGroup viewFrame = new FrameLayout(this);
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int maxAllowedNumberOfRows = (int) Math.floor((displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density) / PLAYER_VIEW_MINIMUM_HEIGHT_DP);
        int numberOfRows = Math.min(maxAllowedNumberOfRows, MAX_NUMBER_OF_ROWS_WANTED);
        int interImagePaddingPx = (int) displayMetrics.density * INTER_IMAGE_PADDING_DP;
        int imageHeight = (displayMetrics.heightPixels / numberOfRows) - interImagePaddingPx;
        int imageWidth = (int) (imageHeight * THUMBNAIL_ASPECT_RATIO);

        imageWallView = new ImageWallView(this, imageWidth, imageHeight, interImagePaddingPx);
        viewFrame.addView(imageWallView, MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT);

        thumbnailView = new YouTubeThumbnailView(this);
        thumbnailView.initialize(Constant.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);

        flippingView = new FlippingView(this, this, imageWidth, imageHeight);
        flippingView.setFlipDuration(INITIAL_FLIP_DURATION_MILLIS);
        viewFrame.addView(flippingView, imageWidth, imageHeight);

        playerView = new FrameLayout(this);
        playerView.setId(id_videoPlayer);
        playerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        viewFrame.addView(playerView, imageWidth, imageHeight);

        playerFragment = YouTubePlayerFragment.newInstance();
        playerFragment.initialize(Constant.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(id_videoPlayer, playerFragment).commit();

        flipDelayHandler = new FlipDelayHandler();

        setContentView(viewFrame);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader thumbnailLoader) {
        thumbnailView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "lol! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
        this.thumbnailLoader = thumbnailLoader;
        thumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(new ThumbnailListener());
        maybeStartDemo();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            if (errorDialog == null || !errorDialog.isShowing()) {
                errorDialog = errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST);
                errorDialog.show();
            }
        } else {
            String errorMessage = String.format( errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasResumed) {
        VideoWallActivity.this.player = player;
        player.setPlayerStyle(PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
        player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(new VideoListener());
        maybeStartDemo();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            if (errorDialog == null || !errorDialog.isShowing()) {
                errorDialog = errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST);
                errorDialog.show();
            }
        } else {
            String errorMessage = String.format( errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void maybeStartDemo() {
        if (activityResumed && player != null && thumbnailLoader != null && state.equals(State.UNINITIALIZED)) {
            thumbnailLoader.setPlaylist(PLAYLIST_ID); // loading the first thumbnail will kick off demo         
            state = State.LOADING_THUMBNAILS;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            if (errorDialog != null && errorDialog.isShowing()) {
                errorDialog.dismiss();
            }
            errorDialog = null;
            playerFragment.initialize(Constant.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
            thumbnailView.initialize(Constant.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        activityResumed = true;
        if (thumbnailLoader != null && player != null) {
            if (state.equals(State.UNINITIALIZED)) {
                maybeStartDemo();
            } else if (state.equals(State.LOADING_THUMBNAILS)) {
                loadNextThumbnail();
            } else {
                if (state.equals(State.VIDEO_PLAYING)) {
                    player.play();
                }
                flipDelayHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, FLIP_DURATION_MILLIS);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        flipDelayHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        activityResumed = false;
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (thumbnailLoader != null) {
            thumbnailLoader.release();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) private void flipNext() {
        if (!nextThumbnailLoaded || state.equals(State.VIDEO_LOADING)) {
            return;
        }

        if (state.equals(State.VIDEO_ENDED)) {
            flippingCol = videoCol;
            flippingRow = videoRow;
            state = State.VIDEO_BEING_FLIPPED_OUT;
        } else {
            Pair<Integer, Integer> nextTarget = imageWallView.getNextLoadTarget();
            flippingCol = nextTarget.first;
            flippingRow = nextTarget.second;
        }

        flippingView.setX(imageWallView.getXPosition(flippingCol, flippingRow));
        flippingView.setY(imageWallView.getYPosition(flippingCol, flippingRow));
        flippingView.setFlipInDrawable(thumbnailView.getDrawable());
        flippingView.setFlipOutDrawable(imageWallView.getImageDrawable(flippingCol, flippingRow));
        imageWallView.setImageDrawable(flippingCol, flippingRow, thumbnailView.getDrawable());
        imageWallView.hideImage(flippingCol, flippingRow);
        flippingView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        flippingView.flip();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) @Override
    public void onFlipped(FlippingView view) {
        imageWallView.showImage(flippingCol, flippingRow);
        flippingView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        if (activityResumed) {
            loadNextThumbnail();

            if (state.equals(State.VIDEO_BEING_FLIPPED_OUT)) {
                state = State.VIDEO_FLIPPED_OUT;
            } else if (state.equals(State.VIDEO_CUED)) {
                videoCol = flippingCol;
                videoRow = flippingRow;
                playerView.setX(imageWallView.getXPosition(flippingCol, flippingRow));
                playerView.setY(imageWallView.getYPosition(flippingCol, flippingRow));
                imageWallView.hideImage(flippingCol, flippingRow);
                playerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                player.play();
                state = State.VIDEO_PLAYING;
            } else if (state.equals(State.LOADING_THUMBNAILS) && imageWallView.allImagesLoaded()) {
                state = State.VIDEO_FLIPPED_OUT; // trigger flip in of an initial video
                flippingView.setFlipDuration(FLIP_DURATION_MILLIS);
                flipDelayHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }
        }
    }

    private void loadNextThumbnail() {
        nextThumbnailLoaded = false;
        if (thumbnailLoader.hasNext()) {
            thumbnailLoader.next();
        } else {
            thumbnailLoader.first();
        }
    }

    /**
     * A handler that periodically flips an element on the video wall.
     */
    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    private final class FlipDelayHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            flipNext();
            sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, FLIP_PERIOD_MILLIS);
        }

    }

    /**
     * An internal listener which listens to thumbnail loading events from the
     * {@link YouTubeThumbnailView}.
     */
    private final class ThumbnailListener implements YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener {
        @Override
        public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnail, String videoId) {
            nextThumbnailLoaded = true;

            if (activityResumed) {
                if (state.equals(State.LOADING_THUMBNAILS)) {
                    flipNext();
                } else if (state.equals(State.VIDEO_FLIPPED_OUT)) {
                    // load player with the video of the next thumbnail being flipped in
                    state = State.VIDEO_LOADING;
                    player.cueVideo(videoId);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnail, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason reason) {
            loadNextThumbnail();
        }

    }

    private final class VideoListener implements YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void onLoaded(String videoId) {
            state = State.VIDEO_CUED;
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoEnded() {
            state = State.VIDEO_ENDED;
            imageWallView.showImage(videoCol, videoRow);
            playerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason errorReason) {
            if (errorReason == YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason.UNEXPECTED_SERVICE_DISCONNECTION) {
                // player has encountered an unrecoverable error - stop the demo
                flipDelayHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                state = State.UNINITIALIZED;
                thumbnailLoader.release();
                thumbnailLoader = null;
                player = null;
            } else {
                state = State.VIDEO_ENDED;
            }
        }

        // ignored callbacks

        @Override
        public void onVideoStarted() { }

        @Override
        public void onAdStarted() { }

        @Override
        public void onLoading() { }

    }
}
```

In this way, there are a list of videos in the playlist, each video will start automatically when the first is finished. I need to click each video in the wall for start it

Answer (score 2):

You can add an onClickListener to the ImageViews in the ImageWallView.java class, something like this:

```
for (int col = 0; col < numberOfColumns; col++) {
  for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; row++) {
    int elementIdx = getElementIdx(col, row);
    if (images[elementIdx] == null) {
      ImageView thumbnail = new ImageView(context);
      thumbnail.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(imageWidth, imageHeight));
      images[elementIdx] = thumbnail;
      unInitializedImages.add(elementIdx);
      thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              ImageWallView.this.context.startActivity(YouTubeIntents.createPlayVideoIntentWithOptions(
                      ImageWallView.this.context, (String)v.getTag(), true, false));
          }
      });
    }
    addView(images[elementIdx]);
  }
}
```

Then you will need to add the video id as the tag in *YouTubeThumbnailView* in **VideoWallActivity.java**

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

You can use ImageView OnClickListener as suggested in previous answer: (onSizeChanged in ImageWallView.java)

```
for (int col = 0; col < numberOfColumns; col++) {
  for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; row++) {
    int elementIdx = getElementIdx(col, row);
    if (images[elementIdx] == null) {
      ImageView thumbnail = new ImageView(context);
      thumbnail.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(imageWidth, imageHeight));
      images[elementIdx] = thumbnail;
      unInitializedImages.add(elementIdx);
      thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              ImageWallView.this.context.startActivity(YouTubeIntents.createPlayVideoIntentWithOptions(
                      ImageWallView.this.context, (String)v.getTag(), true, false));
          }
      });

    }
    addView(images[elementIdx]);
  }
}
```

Then you need to store video id to the calling view of ImageWallView . (set and get tag is also used to store objects between views).
To get the child view of ImageWallView, use imageWallView.getChildAt(index). index is the position of ImageView which is clicked on ImageWallView. to get this index, use getElementIdx(col,row). You need to make this method public in  ImageWallView.java.

**EDITED**

To use the Video ID of current thumbnail, Store the VideoID in onFlipped event. This is because onThumbnailLoaded the VideoID of next thumbnail available which immediately get Flipped and available on IamgeWallView. As VideoID is not available in onFlipped event, use it from onThumbnailLoaded event

Here it is:
Declare below string in class

```
private String strThumbnailVideoId;
```

set VideoID in onThumbnailLoaded event (in VideoWallActivity.java) into strThumbnailVideoId. This video ID will be of next thumbnail which will be flipped.

```
@Override
public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnail, String videoId) {
  nextThumbnailLoaded = true;      
  strThumbnailVideoId = videoId;
  if (activityResumed) {
    if (state.equals(State.LOADING_THUMBNAILS)) {
      flipNext();
    } else if (state.equals(State.VIDEO_FLIPPED_OUT)) {
      // load player with the video of the next thumbnail being flipped in
      state = State.VIDEO_LOADING;
      player.cueVideo(videoId);
    }
  }
}
```

Now set the strThumbnailVideoId in onFlipped as a ImageWallView tag.

```
@Override
public void onFlipped(FlippingView view) {
imageWallView.showImage(flippingCol, flippingRow);
flippingView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
imageWallView.getChildAt(imageWallView.getElementIdx(flippingCol,     flippingRow)).setTag(strThumbnailVideoId);     
......
......
```

Comment: Hey, this works fine. However It loads the next flipping video instead of current one. What am I missing :) ?

Comment: See the EDITED section of the post. Hope this will solve your doubt. To use the Video ID of current thumbnail, Store the VideoID in onFlipped event. This is because onThumbnailLoaded the VideoID of next thumbnail available which immediately get Flipped and available on IamgeWallView. As VideoID is not available in onFlipped event, use it from onThumbnailLoaded event.

Comment: Awesome ;) I'm dumb. Thanks. I got one more question, how can I detect if video has finished, and make the player close automaticly ? I did see 

'  public void onVideoEnded() {
            state = State.VIDEO_ENDED;
            imageWallView.showImage(videoCol, videoRow);
            playerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }' 

call but It's in MainActivity, and doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Nevermind, that was quite simple. Enough to change False parameter to true in this line `ImageWallView.this.context, (String)v.getTag(), true, false (here true)))`